# TypeScript generic interface documentation/comments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following interfaces and types:

```js
type TransformOptions = 'auto' | 'binary' | 'json';

interface Get {
    /**
     * How long to keep the value in cache
     */
    maxAge?: number
    /**
     * Whether to decrypt the param or not
     */
    decrypt?: boolean
    /**
     * Whether to transform the param or not
     */
    transform?: TransformOptions
}

interface GetTransformJson extends Get {
    /**
     * Whether to transform the param or not (json)
     */
    transform?: 'json'
}

interface GetTransformNo extends Get {
    transform?: never
}

type GetOptions = GetTransformNo | GetTransformJson | undefined;

type RetType<O = undefined> =
    undefined extends O ? string :
    O extends GetTransformNo ? string :
    O extends GetTransformJson ? Record<string, any> :
    never;
```

Which I use in this (simplified) function:

```
declare function apiCall(name: string): Promise<string>;


const getParameters = async <O extends GetOptions | undefined>(name: string, options?: O): Promise<RetType<O> | undefined> => {
    const value = await apiCall(name);

    if (options?.transform === 'json') {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(value);

        return parsed as RetType<O>;
    } else {
        return value as RetType<O>;
    }
}
```

When I use this function (see example below), I would like to have annotations/comments that document each one of the fields of the `options` interface like below:

[image]

but instead, since it's a generic (I think), I get nothing:
[image]

Since I'm building a library, I would like to have comments/documentation for all the properties in the `options` object, but using the current generics setup I am not able to.

---

EDIT 1
Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75827278/2304421), I have updated the signature of the function to this:

```
const getParameters = async <O extends GetOptions | undefined = undefined>(
    name: string,
    options?: O & GetOptions
): Promise<RetType<O> | undefined> => {
```

Now the docs/comment on the `transform` method work and seem to get picked up from the `GetTransformJson` interface (see `(json)` at the end of the comment:
[image]

However if I try to do the same but with a different attribute that comes from the base interface (i.e. `decrypt`) I don't get the docs/comments:

[image]

Comment: `getParameters<GetOptions>(...)`

Comment: If I do that the whole file breaks (I can't attach a playground link because the URL is too long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it should be safe to intersect `O` with `Get` to "carry over" doc comments:

```
const getParameters = async <O extends GetOptions | undefined = undefined>(
    name: string,
    options?: O & Get
): Promise<RetType<O> | undefined> => {
```

Also, you should probably default to `undefined` for `O`.

Unfortunately, this won't allow you to use the doc comment specific to `GetTransformJson`...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbA8mYASw1SgF4oAiBAV2A0qgB8qAjQpBOERlygKxQlKAbgBQYjsAhw0CAMbQA4hGBQA3mKjaoAegBU+rTqj6oACQwB3KABsSAcyj0oAawgQwzgBbQAbgi2NNAcUPIKvsY6+rpRUNgIAB4Agg4QAPwAXFBINNisMuImBkYmplAA6r7AvnDOGFAAJhDy3AQ+0GBcCNhQWDkYwHGmsSbNreDAWVCsGBi2EMhFOiXDZlWqtfXOiKiYOB1QXYi9-UiDa6M6wLvoWNjT8Mh3OPhEJCjiAL4SUjJyiigKmATz29wAUkIkFAIIlpEhGiggaoNHFVmV1tUti4bs99r0ap1uqc6uc1AAKQQkACUlziuLBOGmAihojEP0kSGksgUylUoJe2AAcg1YfDEci1JoTAzBdMkBA-IV2RJQJBJW9iKQKMCBfiRcxJXqIVDDTQERA0BwII1xGI1dAAEr88AQAA8uHIUHNzStCsaAD4vT7LdbGjC4RAEUjcHF0lAUDcOA44tlPWKoxLdbd9Rg4wmk0gUyY0xHxUjs3iTSR8875FhGm7E3BkwAaKDIEAB1M5RXKsTjWxcaBoc3yd7QhBgQgAYUCtnJnGwEGyzeT1OyAAU4BhsIQUO610WA3b66g1GlgJviaoZEiKAgUCAkPIoB6y5mK6pNR8zRa-Tawb-mGAbknES4rgWLZFq2cQYAQWooNMnoAGSSmIG5QNuu77u6zogq6HpBiwIYAYG5BBtKOhnomUABEE0APlYCCEGoU6zvOi49BA1J2iYhBoFA5LwROSEAHSyvi5BkBQLLCNSqJlNRHxqMcB7hhQ4IAMq4EKYlqRA5L0cEvESEp2hwKoNBwNCBnho+UD4TAhG4CecRfDCtgHop5mWcA1nQsZ0AOU5LluSYPxfHal7Xict5wCg5KUNgIC6McPSUO26g7FWODZHJSCMF8pkxTe3KJclqXpdgmUaE0LRtMA2Q3MEUDFeIQA)

---

After some experimentation, I found this:

```
const getParameters = async <O extends GetOptions | undefined = undefined>(
    name: string,
    options?: O & (O extends GetTransformNo ? GetTransformNo : O extends GetTransformJson ? GetTransformJson : Get)
): Promise<RetType<O> | undefined> => {
```

which *does* preserve doc comments specific to `GetTransformJson` and `GetTransformNo`, but at the cost of readability and maintenance.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbA8mYASw1SgF4oAiBAV2A0qgB8qAjQpBOERlygKxQlKAbgBQYjsAhw0CAMbQA4hGBQA3mKjaoAegBU+rTqj6oACQwB3KABsSAcyj0oAawgQwzgBbQAbgi2NNAcUPIKvsY6+rpRUNgIAB4Agg4QAPwAXFBINNisMuImBkYmplAA6r7AvnDOGFAAJhDy3AQ+0GBcCNhQWDkYwHGmsSbNreDAWVCsGBi2EMhFOiXDZlWqtfXOiKiYOB1QXYi9-UiDa6M6wLvoWNjT8Mh3OPhEJCjiAL4SUjJyiigKmATz29wAUkIkFAIIlpEhGiggaoNHFVmV1tUti4bs99r0ap1uqc6uc1AAKQQkACUlziuLBOGmAihojEP0kSGksgUylUoJe2AAcg1YfDEci1JoTAzBdMkBA-IV2RJQJBJW9iKQKMCBfiRcxJXqIVDDTQERA0BwII1xGI1dAAEr88AQAA8uHIUHNzStCsaAD4vT7LdbGjC4RAEUjcHF0lAUDcOA44tlPWKoxLdbd9Rg4wmk0gUyY0xHxUjs3iTSR8875FhGm7E3BkwAaKDIEAB1M5RXKsTjWxcaBoc3yd7QhBgQgAYUCtnJnGwEGyzeT1OyAAU4BhsIQUO610WA3b66g1GlgJviaoZEiKAgUCAkPIoB6y5mK6pNR8zRa-Tawb-mGAbknES4rgWLZFq2cQYAQWooNMnoAGRQOS6aRtGRo5vcBrxpWjLCg0pYZthhGCpCJBQAR-K4TgVHQtkwK0huUDbru+7us6IKuh6QYsCGAGBuQQbSjoZ6JlAARBNAD5WAghBqFOs7zouPQQNSdomIQaDofBE5IQAdLK+LkGQFAssI1KomUEkfGoxwHuGFDggAyrgQpGU5EDkjJwRaRIdnaHAqg0HA0I+eGj5QDxMB8bgJ5xF8MK2AetnBaFwDhdC-nQDFcUJUlJg-F8dqXteJy3nAKDkpQ2AgLoxw9JQ7bqDsVY4NkVlIIwXyBRVN7crV9WNc12CtRoTQtG0wDZDcwRQP14hAA)

Comment: You're the MVP, thank you so much for the quick answer! (marking as accepted as soon as SO lets me)

Comment: Follow up question: in your same playground, try to put `getParameters('my-param', { decrypt: true })`, how do I also get the comment on the `decrypt` property? It seems that the ones from the base interface don't get propagated

Comment: @Andre.IDK Really? It works for me in the playground...

Comment: I have updated the OP with screenshots using your suggested signature

Comment: @Andre.IDK Oh I see, I was using the wrong playground. I updated the post as well. It seems like you can't really get "dynamic" doc comments.

Comment: Okay, that's good enough for me at this stage, thank you!

Comment: @Andre.IDK No wait, I found a really dirty hack...

Comment: Happy to take a look :D - EDIT - Thank you for updating!